# What's the DC of a Devourer's "trap essence" attack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, saving-throw, difficulty-class

What's the DC of a Devourer's "trap essence" attack?

I checked several sources on the internet, but they just say the DC is "charisma-based" without saying what the number is. They have also mentioned negating the negative level's DC is 19, but none has mentioned the DC for the "trap essence" attack itself. It seems Google isn't helping me out. Can someone tell me what the DC of it is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The SRD version is broken and doesn't work

The original version from the Monster Manual states:

> ##### Trap Essence (Su)
>
> The devourer is named for its ability to consume an enemy's life
> essence. To do so, it must forgo its normal melee attacks and make a
> trap essence attack. This requires a normal attack roll to hit but
> deals no damage. **The affected creature must succeed at a Fortitude
> save (DC 19) or die instantly.**

Note both the DC 19 Fortitude Save as well as the "or die instantly". Compare to the SRD version:

> The devourer is named for its ability to consume an enemy’s life essence. To do so, it must forgo its normal melee attacks and make a trap essence attack. This requires a normal attack roll but *deals no damage*. **The save DC is Charisma-based.**

- Which save, Fortitude as in MM?
- How is the SRD Devourer supposed to trap "a slain creature’s essence" if the way it has to Trap Essence deals no damage and does not cause death?

Comment: I disagree that it's _broken_, it's just _implicit_. When an ability gives a DC for the target to overcome, the effect is binary unless otherwise specified: pass the save => golden, fail the save => suffer. Hence, in this case, if the target fails, its life essence is trapped... and implicitly, since the ability is about trapping a slain target's life essence, the target is dead. Explicit would be better, sure. Not "broken" though.

Comment: @MatthieuM. that SRD one doesn't even mention what save to roll.  It is really, really broken.  Looks like a copy-editing mistake, where the useful sentence was overwritten by the "save DC is charisma-based" extra info accidentally.

Comment: @Yakk: Good point, I missed that which save to roll had been left out. If the answer had pointed it out, I would have agreed that it was, indeed, broken.

Answer (score 13):

### 19

The general method for calculating the DC of a [supernatural ability](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#supernaturalAbilities) is

> 10 + ½ the creature’s HD + the creature’s ability modifier (usually
> Charisma).

A [Devourer](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/devourer.htm) has 12 HD and a charisma score of 17. So the DC for its supernatural *Trap Essence* attack is 10 + 6 + 3 = 19